# docker-compose.yml with nginx and react and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx

I want build a docker-compose.yml and use nginx proxy my service,
I have 3 services one is nodejs express, use "yarn start" to run service.

Other 2 services is react app build to nginx image like:

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY /build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY /nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 3000
```

The nginx.conf for react(both) is:

```
server{
    listen 3000;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
  signup:
    driver: bridge

services:
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
      - background
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: signup-nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - signup

  frontend:
    image: signup:frontend
    container_name: signup-frontend
    restart: always
    networks:
      - signup

  backend:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    image: signup:backend
    container_name: signup-backend
    command: sh -c "yarn migrate:r && yarn start"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - signup

  background:
    image: background
    container_name: background
    restart: always
    networks:
      - signup
```

The nginx.conf for docker-compose.yml is:

```
upstream frontend {
    server frontend:3000;
}

upstream backend {
    server backend:8000;
}

upstream background {
    server background:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /signup {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }

    location /background {
        proxy_pass http://background;
    }
}
```

I want to use routing to split different react services like,
localhost/signup/ go to "frontend" react,
localhost/background/ go to "background" react,
localhost/api/ go to backend nodejs,
now /api works, /signup and /background not works,
what should I do?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens?  Are the port numbers 8000 and 3000 correct, and are the respective services listening on 0.0.0.0 and those ports?  This setup seems fundamentally correct to me; I might remove a number of the Compose options but the overall structure and configuration look right.

Comment: When compose up, localhost/api/ works,but localhost/signup and localhost/background not works,in Dev tools, I saw network fetch html successfully,but .js and .css.It seems fetch localhost/static/js/bundle.js.Shouldn't fetch localhost/signup/static/js/bundle.js?